# Rejection in app store because "should have all included URLs fully functional"

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I recently uploaded an app to the app store and it got rejected. The reason for the rejection was:

> Apps should have all included URLs fully functional when you submit it for review, such as support and privacy policy URLs

As far the app is concerned it works perfectly, parses webservices and there are no bugs. The thing is: were should I include support and privacy policy URLs?

Comment: https://www.iubenda.com/blog/2013/06/14/privacy-policy-for-ios-apps/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you submit an app to the app store, you include URLs in your submission. These URLs are displayed on the app page inside of the iTunes store. It sounds like the URLs you added to your submission were non-functional.

Comment: yup there is one url field..named as "Support URL".i dont have any support url and hence i gave "http://google.com ".but i dont find any field for privacy policies.

Comment: Looks like Apple found out you weren't Google, then.

Comment: should i give my company's mail url?any idea.

Comment: What would possibly possess you to type google.com as your support URL? Just throw up a web page on your company site that has *anything at all* (even just an email link), or maybe your company's About page, or whatever. Granted, a real support page is good for the user, but if you don't have one, you have to have *something*.

Comment: this was not a problem 5 months back.since the renewal of new app store guideliness i m expected to stick on to the guidelines.its an U.S based web development company and we dont own a website.

Comment: You're a development company that doesn't have a web site?

Comment: @ceejayoz: No? Hrm, I thought there was, but you may be right. Why have I seen +2 reps given out before then?

Comment: +2s go to people who accept answers.

Comment: Use getsatisfaction.com or a similar service to get a support webpage for free

Answer (score 4):

To submit an app, you must have functioning web sites with information about support for your own particular app and about your own particular privacy policy.  A web site about something else is not suitable.  If you don't have a web site, create one on some low cost or free web hosting service, or hire someone to do so for you.